# ExtJS button style

Tags: extjs

I have to change style of buttons in my app. Each button can its own style. So I have to do it through javascript dynamically. Button has `setStyle()` in doc. But it doesn't work like that. How to achieve this?

Here is an example!

```
Ext.create('Ext.Button', {
    text: 'Click me',
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    style : {
        'color' : 'red',
        'font-size' : '15px',
        'font-weight' : 'bold'
    },
    handler: function() {
        this.setStyle({'color':'blue'});
        alert('Style applied!');
    }
});
```

Comment: I don't see a "fieldStyle" config for butttons in the docs. Have you tried [style](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Ext.button.Button.html#cfg-style)?

Comment: Please add a try or a Fiddle

Comment: [Fields have a fieldStyle](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.1/classic/Ext.form.field.Base.html#cfg-fieldStyle), [buttons haven't](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.1/classic/Ext.button.Button.html#cfg-fieldStyle)

Comment: You can use `setStyle`

Comment: `setStyle` works only for alignment. I want to apply color/fon-size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inspect and see where Sencha sets the color, for example in the button case it is set on the .x-btn-inner element.

**this.getEl().select('.x-btn-inner').setStyle({'color':'blue'});**

See fiddle
https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/1obm

edit : `select` is not documented. Use `down` instead.

`this.getEl().down('.x-btn-inner').setStyle({'color':'blue'});`

Comment: Good one. But `select` is not documented! But `down` works here.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is doing just what its supposed to do, however it is changing font color on the anchor tag which is just the wrapper for the span that is holding the text which you are trying to change color of.

My suggestion is to use cls property instead of style. Than toggle its styles..

here's a fiddle https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/1o92

hope it helps

Comment: Thanks. I know this. There can be different combinations of style for each button. That's insane to add classes for all these combinations. And again, this is `Ext.button`, why should I worry about anchor tag? :)

Answer (score 1):

As bullettain suggested using classes will be the maintainable way.

How ever for your specific requirement use the below code.

Ext button are nothing but a `<a>` tag, and underneath text is a `<span>` with class ".x-btn-inner"

```
Ext.application({
name: 'Fiddle',

launch: function () {
    Ext.create('Ext.Button', {
        text: 'Click me',
        renderTo: Ext.getBody(),

        handler: function () {
            // Javascript style
            this.el.query('span .x-btn-inner')[0].style.color = 'red';
        }
    });
}


  });
```

https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/1oar

Comment: To use class I have to know the style being applied. Here I don't know what style will be applied. I have some style object which includes color, align, font-size and/or font-style. I just have to set that to button. It works for form fields by using `setFieldStyle`. I just need similar kind of implementation. Anyway, I can have some work around like setting each of them from the passed object similarly your impl..

Comment: Let's hope that Sencha is not modifying the frameworks conventions if you do it like this. I wouldn't do this like this ever.

Answer (score 1):

If you work with Sencha CMD you could easily add SASS mixins for the button.
In the example below I use the mixins 'default-toolbar' and 'default-small' as an example. But you could make mixins for every kind of button and call them 'redalert', 'greenpeace', 'blueplanet' or whatever your want.

A SASS mixin has the great advantage that it works with the dynamic values that you don't modify. So if you change the color of the button to red, the click or hover is automatically modified to a light red for example.

See also: [Link to Sencha Docs for button UI mixin](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.2/classic/Ext.button.Button.html#css_mixin-extjs-button-ui)

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'Fiddle',

    launch: function () {
       Ext.create('Ext.Button', {
           text: 'Click me',
           renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
           scope: this,
           ui: 'default-toolbar',
           handler: function (b) {
               console.log(b.ui);
               b.setUI(b.ui !== 'default-small' ? 'default-small' : 'default-toolbar');
           }
       });
   }
```

})

Answer (score 0):

Use 'cls' config of button. You can have different classes for different states of button like **disabledCls** when button is disabled, **iconCls** to show icon. Also you can add or remove cls runtime using **addCls** and **removeCls** methods.

Comment: Thanks brother. But I really wanted any combination of style to button at runtime. Having classes for all combinations is difficult. The selected answer works for any combination of any style.